# Rig veda and creation

Tags: rig-veda

does rig veda know how the universe came into being?does rig veda believe the universe is constantly cyclical?ıs there a parallel universe infinity?

Comment: "ıs there a parallel universe infinity?" Not in the Vedas but there are references to other universes in the puranas.

Answer (score 3):

There are various creation myths in the Rig Veda, including the following –

- the famous Nāsadīya Sūkta (RV 10.129) where existence emerges, initially in the form of the One, by some process that is not fully understood – [which I have discussed here](https://medium.com/sanskrit-literature-and-indian-philosophy/theology-and-indian-philosophy-77b9e989f2d4)
- the pulling apart of a primordial whole into earth and sky by Indra (RV 5.31.6, RV 10.113.5 etc.) - [which I have discussed here](https://medium.com/sanskrit-literature-and-indian-philosophy/creation-in-the-rig-veda-8772c3569d20)
- the sacrifice of a cosmic Person (puruṣa) to form the universe in the famous Puruṣa Sūkta (RV 10.90)
- the crafting of the universe by Viśvakarman from the wood of a tree (RV 10.81)

Comment: Why are these so many creation stories? Are all of them true?

Comment: Rig Veda is not the work of a single author, but rather a carefully compiled edition of verses from several hundred earlier ṛṣis (sages or poets).  These ṛṣis would each have their own diverse perspectives to share based on their own family traditions and their own intuitive insights.  Beyond this, it's difficult to speculate.

Comment: Makes sense. Welcome to Hinduism.SE. We also have a [meta](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) where we discuss site policies.

Comment: Thanks, meta is helpful